# Выполнение кода не в главном потоке без лагов основного потока

Tags: java, android

Я пробовал выводить загрузку HTML кода сайта в String в AsyncTask, IntentService, ExecutorService, еще что-то пробовал и везде задача выполняется, но  при вызывании нового потока основной зависает на секунду. Что может быть не так и что надо учитывать, чтобы это избежать?

Для получения HTML я использую библиотеку Ion, т.к. другими способами не получалось брать html без символов, вместо русского текста. Запрос Ion выполняется в уже созданном потоке.

Работа проблемного запроса:

В AsyncTask получаем html от Ion, результат отправляется в класс для парсинга (заметил странную особенность, значения UI потока спокойно меняются без runOnUiThread, НО точно так же обрабатывается и полностью рабочий запрос).

Выполнение метода парсинга (парсится таблица с сайта в TableLayout):
Сплиты, реплейсы, for(большой, обрабатывает все данные таблицы средней величины), создание TableRow и добавление его в TableLayout.

Это все, что делается в потоке в момент провисания, больше ничего.

Comment: покажите как вы использовали AsyncTask

Comment: Я удалил тот AsyncTask и для демонстрации сделал новый. Я создаю 2 таких экземпляра класса с AsyncTask, проблема возникает при работе второго (при первом провисаний нет, только при втором). Пытаюсь найти причину. К данным в главном потоке обращаюсь через Activity.runOnUiThread, даже не знаю, что может быть проблемой.

Comment: Вы хотите именно избежать зависания на одну секунду при старте таска? Тут дело может быть и в слабом девайсе на пример.

Comment: Девайс не слабый, первый таск же выполняется, второй зависает. Просто загрузка с двух разных сайтов, для них разный код. Первый выполняется отлично, второй где-то стопорится и я не знаю почему.

Comment: Так покажите код, может в нем и правда есть проблема

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий как раз редактирую и сокращаю, чтобы выложить, он просто объемный очень.

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий обновил описание. Код большой, поэтому написал все, что в нем происходит (прочитал каждую строчку, все верно и ничего больше не происходит).

Comment: Боюсь этого все еще не достаточно. Мне, например, приходит в голову вариант, что вы делаете часть работы в onPostExecute, а он этот метод выполняется в том потоке, в котором вы вызвали AsyncTask.execute(). Это бы объяснило лаги интерфейса, но сказать наверняка из описания не выйдет. Можете выложить код на гитхаб/гитлаб/любом сервисе для шаринга кода

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий В том и дело, что все выполняется в doinBackground. Хорошо, выложу на гитхаб.

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий добавил ссылку на гитхаб.

Comment: `Ion` заворачивать в таск не нужно - там и так асинхронный запрос. А вот результат возвращается в главный поток (через `Callback`) - соответственно весь парсинг у вас происходит в UI-треде. В общем вам нужно завернуть в таск не `Ion`, а вызов `UpdateData.updateData(...)`

Comment: @woesss Спасибо! Все отлично.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо выводить в новый поток Callback от Ion, а не сам запрос Ion.